# Sharp photos with kit lens

Tags: canon, exposure, kit-lens, exposure-compensation, canon-80d

Hello I have a 80D with a kit lens 18-135 IS f/3.5-5.6

I take photos of my kids indoors and it seems that I’m almost always shooting at iso 32000 and up and it seems like everything is grainy (noise)

Question is can I get sharp images in low light with a kit lens or do I need a faster lens f/1.8 or something?

This comes to my next point. I was told that stopping down to at least f/8 will be the sharpest but in my situation I’m wide open with at least 1/60 shutter speed with high iso. Also I was told that shooting wide open I can miss focus. Is this true?

Is there something I can change up or am I screwed?

Comment: Related: [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp).

Comment: I actually read that, since it didn’t say lowlight I ignored it. I’ll take a look at it. 

Thanks

Comment: Well, [the duplicate question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/113966/how-to-get-sharper-photos-with-a-kit-lens-when-in-low-light-conditions) might have better answers for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

As the word photography mean (photos - light, graphos - write) you need light. Faster lens may help a bit, but not so much. One way is to go outside where you will find much more light. Other option is to use flash. This can help you to freeze the motion and to lower the ISO as the impulse of flash is powerful.

Comment: On my 80D I have built in flash. Can I use it artistically? My subjects won’t be too far away. Plus I can set it manually not ETTL and turn the power down. How will that work?

Comment: @Jcb, stackexchange isn't like a messageboard with extended discussion. It's more of a Q&A database, so asking separate questions is probably better. But also searching through to see if your question's been asked before you post would be best.  Maybe try [Without modification, is the built-in pop-up flash EVER appropriate?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22233) and [Does it make sense for me, as a beginner, to buy a speedlight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125439)

Comment: @inkista Thanks. I just opened up an account today on stack exchange. And needed the question. I will do research first then ask. Also do you your searches using the stack exchange search engine or do you use google? Like site:<site name> Keywords

Comment: @Jcb I just use the search box at the top of the page. You might also want to [take the tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at [the Help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help) to get a sense of what SE is. Also, like all SEs, we have [a Meta area](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/) where we discuss issues about using this stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks @inkista I will look at the tour again and make sure that I stop asking duplicate questions. I hate being the n00b in the house lol

Comment: @Jcb, don't worry too much! :) The fact that you joined SE already puts you way ahead of most of the pack. Welcome to stackexchange!